# in software level , Is there any way to touch screen iOS device without xCode-instruments or jail-breaking?

Tags: ios, macos, touch, instruments, jailbreak

I am using x-Code instruments command-line tool for automated-testing iPhone4 or etc..

But instruments is allowed to used only debugging specified App.
 and VNC requires jail-breaking

Is there any way to  touch screen ( in software level ) iOS without xCode-instruments or jail-breaking?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Even with a jailbreak, sending touches to an iOS device remotely is hard.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11732858)

Comment: @zeeMonkeez This *is* an answer though. It may not be great but it is an attempt to answer the original question.